# Using a regex as a DB field

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have been trying something quite over the top and would like your opinion about it.

I'm using a Postgres DB to store some product information, mainly their family, using a 4 digit code.
let say for instance, that product A can have 1000, 1001 and 1002 while product B has 1003 and 1004.

I want to retrieve the family with the code.

I could do two tables, one with family name, key and other info, another one with all the codes and a link to the familly they are requested. Then, a request like :

```
select familyname 
from family, familycode 
where family.pk = familycode.fk_family AND familycode = '1000'
```

would do the trick
but as I'm quite greedy, I wondered if it wasn't possible to use regex and do a single table with a primary key, a label and a regex that would give the code.

Following the previous example, I would have something like :

```
'pk' 'productA' '100[0-2]{1}'

'pk' 'productB' '100[3-4]{1}'
```

but then, can it really work and give me back my "productA" with a single request entering just '1000' as a code?

Thanks for your attention and for your answers

Best regards

edit :

I'm adding an exemple of the workflow
I have a reference table family, containing an id, a label and a code.

```
'pk' 'productA' 'code1'

'pk' 'productB' 'code2'
```

Depending of the family, my soft will act in consequence. If I have a product A, I will then retriev in another reference table the operation linked to this product

let say that the following stap with then be

Select Operation from table_operation where productref = 'productA'

To get the operation, I need the familly. To get the familly, I have only the code.

As there are a lot of differents codes for a single family, I thought about using a regex IN the table. that's all

Comment: Can't you just select products with a product code < 1003 for product A and >= 1003 for product B?

Comment: With `posgrès`  do you happen to mean PostgreSQL (or just Postgres)?

Comment: @dustmouse : unfortunatly, my goal is to retrieve the family with the product code. I gave a simple example here, but I can have for instance 1002, 1004 for product A and 1003, 1005 for product B. I'm trying to use realy generics request to be used for any product. So I can't do something like "if result is 1002, then use request A else if result is 1003 use request B" and so on. I'm working here with around 30 diferents products that can have 4 to 5 diferents codes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : the storage base is a postgres BD, but I'm using classic SQL from a Qt application to call them

Comment: `where some_column ~ regex_column`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: Im voting to close because isnt clear what you want to do. IMprove your question with some sample data and more details of the result you want

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : that's maybe a lead...I can change the code from '0194', for instance to '.*0194.*'...but then, it won't match '019[0-4]{1}'...yet
I'll try to move from here

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to complicate so much.

In a single table you can have two fields

```
 SELECT family, familyCode
 FROM Your Table
 WHERE family = 100 and familyCode in (0,1,2)
```

You could do the same with one field and a regexp, but you have to be carefull because postgres can use simple indexes only for the left-anchored expressions value LIKE '00%' (important for big tables).

Also the problem with you design is if later you want add another productA to your inventory you are stuck with rigid model. That is why your first solution with two separated table is much better.

Comment: That would do the trick if I wanted to retrieve the family while already knowing what I wanted to retrieve.
Here, in my case, the software following those request must retrieve differents data depending of the familly, and my single entry is the product code. 
If i got a 1000, for instance, I must be able to say "ok, it's product A, I will then retrieve all the data link to product A", but can't say "check if it's product A, if it is, then retrieve all the data link to this"